# How can I get a return code from an ssh command inside a bash function, that is sourced inside another script?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sh

I have a bash script which contains some functions that look like this:

```
my_functions.sh:

do_remote_command () {
    ssh user@hostname "./runScript.sh $var1 $var2"
}
```

I am calling this function via another script that is sourcing the function above like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
source my_functions.sh
do_remote_command
```

I want to get the return code from `./runScript.sh`.  How can I say, "give me the return code for the bottom level command"?

Comment: Add `return $?` at the end of the function.

Comment: The exit status of `do_remote_command` already is the exit status of the last command executed, whose exit status is that of the remote command.

Comment: @chepner Oh, you mean the return code propagates all the way back up?

Comment: Not exactly. If your remote command didn't run `runScript.sh` last, or if your function didn't run `ssh` last, you'd have to do something more complicated.

Comment: What you just said is most likely the case.

Answer (score 0):

modify my_functions.sh as

```
do_remote_command () {
    ssh user@hostname "./runScript.sh $var1 $var2"
    return $?
}
```

...and the new script can echo the return value as

```
#!/bin/bash
source my_functions.sh
echo do_remote_command
```